# Having trouble encrypting my transactions with PayPal on my website

Tags: php, encryption, paypal

For the sake of testing I have this form that I post to PayPal:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="myform">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" >
<input type="hidden" name="cert_id" value="M..value..BD">         
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7----- MIIIEw..encrypted..ss q0cXhdT7fA== -----END PKCS7-----">       
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

When I click the submit button I get this error from PayPal:

> There was a problem verifying the signature of your secure order. Please contact your merchant.

Now it's worth mentioning that I can go through with the transaction if not encrypted, and if I encrypt my post and send without the email for my business I get a different error:

> The email address for the business is not present in the encrypted blob. Please contact your merchant.

Now this tells me that my message is decrypted but not well formatted.
I'm using `function demo_paypal_encrypt( $webform_hash )` from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php

where $webform_hash has the value:

```
$webform_hash = array("business"=>"fboh@hotmake.com", "amount"=> "10", "currency_code"=> "USD");
```

With my real email of course which is not "fboh@hotmake.com", What do you experts think?

Comment: Why would you even be attempting to use such an old, deprecated integration? See the current standard integration guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: Well I had no idea it was a Dinosaur, it's all over the place on PayPal documentations, so I figured why not, anyway it seems I'm just a few steps away from wrapping my head around it, just need a little push.

Comment: Anywhing with PayPal's `/cgi-bin/webscr` is a dinosaur but trying to use that old encryption with it even more so. I don't know if it can be made to work anymore, and wouldn't recommend anyone spend time trying to find out. Not sure what documentation you're finding this "all over the place" on but it's quite the old rabbit hole